# How to write a custom biblatex bbx file: no formatting, just plain data

Tags: biblatex

I'd like to have a biblatex style which would output something along the lines of

```
\begin{journalentry}
\label{label}
\lastname{Smith}
\firstname{John}
\date{1988}
\title{A clever paper}
\journal{Some journal}
\end{journalentry}
```

using the `.bib` and `.bcf` files.

I looked into `debug.bbx`, but it seems to clutter the `.bbl` file with lots of other stuff, and I don't know how to "strip down" its output.

Comment: I don't think a `biblatex` style is what you're looking for here; rather a re-implementation of `biblatex` itself.

Comment: It looks like what you want is some script to do `.bib` conversion to your format. There is little point going through biblatex to do this. Unless ... you need to resolve things like date fields into their components, resolve crossrefs and materialise them etc. In this case, you need to write a custom biber Output module and use its "tool" mode.

Comment: @PLK: what biber & biblatex would do for me is (a) selecting only `\cite`d entries and (b) sorting them.  The rest would be trivial (a natural task for Emacs Lisp;)); (a) would be relatively easy, too, but would need some more text processing, and I thought that I could reuse existing code.  (b) is in general nontrivial (see xindy).

Comment: That said, I'll probably go through another route: processing bibtex-generated bbl file, which is relatively simple (and I already have some Elisp functions to do a similar task).